# Why does my UI button stop responding after a certain amount of time has elapsed?

Tags: ios, swift

My code is supposed to print out the current number of taps recorded, which it does do starting out, but then it randomly stops. Any tips on fixing this?

I think it has something to do with the animation, but I'm not sure what about it is causing the app to stop responding.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var taps = 0 // tracks number of screen taps

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        // get screen dimensions (in points) for current device
        let screenBounds = UIScreen.main.bounds
        let screenWidth = screenBounds.width
        let screenHeight = screenBounds.height

        // create rect
        let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: screenHeight, width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight)
        let view = UIView(frame: rect)
        view.backgroundColor = .red
        self.view.addSubview(view)

        // rising animation
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 5.0, delay: 0.0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            view.frame.origin.y = CGFloat(0)
        }, completion: { finished in
        })
    }

    // when user taps screen
    @IBAction func screenTapped(_ sender: Any) {

        taps += 1 // increment number of taps
        print(taps)
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to add touch on button or screen??

Comment: I added the button in my Main.storyboard, made it take up the entire screen, and then I held control and dragged it into my ViewController.  I want the number of taps to increase whenever the screen is tapped.

Comment: Add tap on entire view instead of button as my below answer

Comment: Read about UIViewPropertyAnimator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var taps = 0 // tracks number of screen taps

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        // get screen dimensions (in points) for current device
        let screenBounds = UIScreen.main.bounds
        let screenWidth = screenBounds.width
        let screenHeight = screenBounds.height

        // create rect
        let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: screenHeight, width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight)
        let view = UIView(frame: rect)
        view.backgroundColor = .red
        self.view.addSubview(view)

        //Add Tap gesture
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(screenTapped))
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

        // rising animation
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 5.0, delay: 0.0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            view.frame.origin.y = CGFloat(0)
        }, completion: { finished in
        })
    }

    // when user taps screen
    @objc func screenTapped() {

        taps += 1 // increment number of taps
        print(taps)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm. Now it starts out working, stops working temporarily during part of the animation, and then starts working again after it finishes. Any thoughts? Thanks so much for your help with this!

Comment: It works except for a small amount of time during the second half of the animation for some reason.

Comment: It stops because when animation is running your view size is changed continues and compiler can't get exact view frame size though.

Comment: Is there a way to get around this, because my goal is to see how many times the user can tap the screen before the animation finishes.

Comment: Can I have the animation run in the background somehow so it doesn't affect the touch region?

Comment: Turns out UIView's block animation by default blocks user interaction, and to get around it you need to pass UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction as one of the options.

Comment: Just accepted it, but I guess I need more rep for the upvote to show lol.